# SQL statement works in Management Studio but not on the website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, select

I have a statement that returns the row that I'm looking for while testing it in SQL Server Management Studio, but when I run it on the website, it returns almost everything in the whole table. There is only one row in the table where the last field = 1. That should be the only row it returns, which works in Management Studio

The statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Reports] 
WHERE [VisitorName] = @VisitorName 
   OR [PlateNumber] = @PlateNumber 
  AND [VisitorBanned] = 1
```

The `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSource2" 
    runat="server"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Reports] WHERE [VisitorName] = @VisitorName OR [PlateNumber] = @PlateNumber AND [VisitorBanned] = 1" 
    ConnectionString="myconnectionstring" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Reports] WHERE [ReportsID] = @ReportsID" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Reports] ([ReportName], [ResidentName], [VisitorName], [PlateNumber], [Report], [Location], [ReportDate], [VisitorBanned]) VALUES (@ReportName, @ResidentName, @VisitorName, @PlateNumber, @Report, @Location, @ReportDate, @VisitorBanned)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Reports] SET [ReportName] = @ReportName, [ResidentName] = @ResidentName, [VisitorName] = @VisitorName, [PlateNumber] = @PlateNumber, [Report] = @Report, [Location] = @Location, [ReportDate] = @ReportDate, [VisitorBanned] = @VisitorBanned WHERE [ReportsID] = @ReportsID" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtboxVisitorName" Name="VisitorName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtboxPlateNumber" Name="PlateNumber" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ReportsID" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReportsID" HeaderText="ReportsID" SortExpression="ReportsID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReportName" HeaderText="ReportName" SortExpression="ReportName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ResidentName" HeaderText="ResidentName" SortExpression="ResidentName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VisitorName" HeaderText="VisitorName" SortExpression="VisitorName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PlateNumber" HeaderText="PlateNumber" SortExpression="PlateNumber" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Report" HeaderText="Report" SortExpression="Report" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReportDate" HeaderText="ReportDate" SortExpression="ReportDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VisitorBanned" HeaderText="VisitorBanned" SortExpression="VisitorBanned" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

The gridview does not show up on page load, then I fill in some fields and call `SqlDataSource2.DataBind(); GridView2.DataBind();`, so I presume the statement is not selecting anything on load, which should be how it is.

Thanks. I don't get why this is happening.

Comment: have you tried putting parenthesis around your OR clause `(NAME or PLATE#) AND BANNED` or is it `NAME OR (PLATE# AND BANNED)`

Comment: Thank you. But why did it work? why is it different in studio?

Comment: Well, I encourage you to investigate the reason why and post your findings as an answer to your own question. Because I actually have no idea.